# Android WebView can not play audio in local HTML5

Tags: javascript, android, html, audio, android-webview

Here is the HTML5

```
audio src="media/hbgm.ogg" loop="true" autoplay="true"
```

I have add the local HTML5 file the `WebView`, I don't know.

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/HelloweenConstruct2/index.html");
WebSettings websettings = webView.getSettings(); 
websettings.setSupportZoom(true); 
websettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true); 
websettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: what version of android, and which device are you testing on?

Comment: Samsung Galaxy Note2 and sony Xperia S